How to add a hyphen after an nth character in Snowflake
I'm trying to add a hyphen in a specific location to a value in Snowflake.  I want the data to look like this:
1-212-1234567- --> 1-212-123-4567-
I tried typing this as:  INSERT(OFFICEPHONE, 9, 1, '-') .  However, I'm seeing that INSERT is overwriting the 9th character.  Is there a different statement that I should use?  Thanks!

When we use the INSERT function, it overwrites the character at the specified position so I suggest you to use the combination of CONCAT and SUBSTR functions, which allows you to insert a substring without overwriting any characters.
You can try with the given Query.
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTR(OFFICEPHONE, 1, 8), 
        '-', 
        SUBSTR(OFFICEPHONE, 9)
    ) AS FORMATTED_OFFICEPHONE
FROM 
    your_table;


If you are looking to update the table to reflect this change, you can use the given UPDATE statement:
UPDATE your_table
SET OFFICEPHONE = CONCAT(SUBSTR(OFFICEPHONE, 1, 8), '-', SUBSTR(OFFICEPHONE, 9))
WHERE condition;

Please let me know if this helps.

is STUFF a function Snowflake supports?

Could you please try to use the given one
SELECT      CONCAT(         SUBSTR(OFFICEPHONE, 1, 8),          '-',          SUBSTR(OFFICEPHONE, 9)     ) AS FORMATTED_OFFICEPHONE FROM      your_table;

Maybe update your answer?

done, please check.

The first paragraph in your answer still refers to STUFF

Thanks for pointing out, this has been done.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

We can tweak your insert to work like an append instead of overwrite. You want a hyphen at the 10th position, not 9th because character index starts at 1 for this function. And you want to replace 0 characters, not 1
select insert('1-212-1234567', 10, 0,'-')

